# How to connect to RavenHQ in c#

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

I'm trying to connect to ravenHQ and I get the

https://database-d0sm.ravenhq.com;Database=DatabaseName;ApiKey=

But how to I add that to the store in c#?

```
    private static IDocumentStore store = new DocumentStore()
    {
        Urls = new[] { "url" },
        Database = "DatabaseName"
    }.Initialize();
```

Okay, in order to do this, I need to downgrade the version of Ravendb in my .net application. The api key is only supported in Ravendb 3.5. So that is the issue.

Comment: Have you checked this https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/Csharp/client-api/setting-up-connection-string ?

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was looking for.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var store = new DocumentStore
{
    ConnectionStringName = "MyRavenConnectionString"
};
```

then in your `web.config` or `app.config`

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="MyRavenConnectionString" connectionString="Url = Url = http://ravendb.mydomain.com;User=user;Password=secret"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Yes this is correct, but make sure that you're using 3.5 as this connection style was depreciated in 4.0